# Parse and enumerate all the fhir elements

Tags: azure

I am using the Firely nuget package to parse a Patient FHIR resource from a bundle. The keyValuePair.Value type is object and for complex fhir datatypes contains nested objects. How do I parse and extract all the fhir elements and its values to a csv format?

Is there an easier way to parse and enumerate the elements without having to typecast the resource first and then extract each individual element inside that resource?

```
string fhirBundle = GetFHIRBundleFromFile();

FhirJsonParser fhirJsonParser = new FhirJsonParser();
Bundle bundle = fhirJsonParser.Parse<Bundle>(fhirBundle);

foreach (var entry in bundle.Entry)
{
    switch (entry.Resource)
    {
        case Patient:
            Patient patient = (Patient)entry.Resource;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in patient)
                  Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key + ": " + keyValuePair.Value.ToString());
             
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Resource is not of type Patient")   
            break;
    }
}
```